# Only getting partial screenprints

Tags: android, screenshot, partial

I am doing a screen print and sending it as an email attachment.  However, oftentimes the screen print has an empty bottom area, about the size that the soft keyboard would have been.  However, I am hiding the keyboard before the screenshot and it is not visible on the screen.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_mail:
            hideKeyboard();
            View v = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
            v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            myBitmap = v.getDrawingCache();
            saveBitmap(myBitmap);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + Consts.SCREENSHOT_PATH_FILENAME;
    File imagePath = new File(filePath);
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        sendMail(filePath);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

public void hideKeyboard() {
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm =(InputMethodManager getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

It is then sent as an email attachment.  Any idea how to get rid of that soft-keyboard sized whitespace in the screen prints?

Comment: If your screenprint is wrong then it is wrong. Why are you talking about sending it in an email?

Comment: The email portion doesn't really matter and I only mentioned it because there was a sendMail in the code; what matters is that the image is not complete.

Comment: You did not explain why you send it as attachment. Please remove all code that is not relevant for your problem. Don't talk about emails if you have a problem making a screendump.

Comment: Ok then, make believe that the sendMail line is not there.  It is of no concern to anyone why it is being sent as an attachment.  What is of interest is that the screenprint is not complete.

If you cannot respond to the issue, consider saying nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the following seems to work. Right after the line:

```
 View v = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
```

I added:

```
v.invalidate();
```

I can't swear that this fixes the problem, but the problem has not occurred again after making this change.  In the past it seems the screen was not always being redrawn after the hiding of the keyboard and the creation of the bitmap, leaving an "empty" spot on the screen where the keyboard had been.